# Styles and themes in Android

Tags: android, android-theme

I'm trying to learn something about styles and themes for Android. I've found that, if I add the `android:theme` attribute in the manifest for Application or Activity, style is applied to the entire app/activity. I think it would be useful to be able to define a style that is applied for example only to buttons. Do you know if there is a way to apply a certain style only for a certain kind on Views, as in CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a general example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
    </style>
    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:buttonStyle>@style/CustomButton</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: A theme can specify default styles for different types of widgets. This example sets a different default style for buttons.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do, just read the official reference:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

**EDIT**

Obviously you'll need to specify the style you create on each button/view you want it to be applied (like in css, for the class attribute)

Comment: The problem is that i did not want to specify the style on every button... i wanted to say: apply this style to every button of the activity. How can it be done?

Comment: See hackbod's example. You define default styles for widgets as part of the activity's theme.